# BATCH : Log for not moved files

Tags: batch-file, logging, move

I use some example on internet to make a very basic batch. The goal of my batch is to move files from a source folder to a destination folder. My batch is located in the source folder and create a destination folder with Md command.

After there's a list of files to move, for each individual file the command is like this:

```
md DestinationFoldername
move "ProjectFree.zip" DestinationFoldername
move "Listofstuff.dat" DestinationFoldername
etc for 1300 lines
```

I write a line for each specific files.

My problem: I want a logfile of files which don't exist in the source folder, I wish to have a log.txt with information like : "ProjectFree.zip don't moved because file don't exist on source folder"

I've tried this:

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=batch.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B
```

But it indicate only "1 files moved", no other information.

Is it possible to make a log.txt with the information I need? How can I achieve that with the simple "move" command in my bat?

Comment: I would suggest you look at using `ROBOCOPY`.

Comment: Do you have a file with the filenames to move (one filename per line)? Very easy to iterate over that file with `for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt")  do echo filename is %%a`.

Comment: @Stephan, myneed is to make one unique batch without list of filename in a txt.

Comment: @Squashman Robocopy is aldready installed on all computer ? it need to be compatible without any additionnal program or txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to iterate over a file. That enables you to use the same code lines with each filename instead of repeating the same code over and over. Since you don't want a separate file, you can use the batchfile itself. A few precautions are necessary for it to work correctly:

- The list has to be at the end of the script.
- You need a unique line to mark the start of the data section (I used `REM DATA:`) (Well, you *could* hardcode the line number, but that's hard to maintain and has to be adapted every time you change anything in the code section)
- You need a `goto :eof` before the data section to not unintentionally start the files
- You need to skip the code (the first `for` loop determines where the data section starts). The second `for` iterates over the data section only

Your code then could look like:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Destination=foldername"
md "%destination%" 2>nul
for /f "delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /nxc:"REM DATA:" "%~dpnx0"') do set /a n=%%n
for /f "usebackq skip=%n% tokens=*" %%a in ("%~dpnx0") do (
  move /y "%%a" "%Destination%\" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo moved:     %%a
  ) || (
    echo NOT moved: %%a
  )
)
goto :eof
REM DATA:
ProjectFree.zip
Listofstuff.dat
notinsource.txt
has space IN name.txt
duplicate.txt
readonlyduplicate.txt
nonexistent.file
```

Adapt the messages to your needs.

Comment: It look great i will give it a go !
EDIT : It works but there isn't a log file wich give all non moved/inexistent files? Is it possible to add a log file to this code ?

Comment: just redirect the messages into a file: `>>failed.log echo NOT moved: %%a`

Comment: exact... i forgot this... Thanks it seems to work like a charm ! I will try it more.

Answer (score 0):

@Kythe

Ok, i realy need to have one only files so i'll choose to take this one. I'm just afraid on the speed on little machine. I have to test.

So the entire code should be this :

@echo off
set LOGFILE=unsuccessfull.log

```
md destinationfolder
move "ProjectFree.zip" "DestinationFoldername" set %file% = "ProjectFree.zip" call :move if %errorlevel% == 1 ( echo Unsuccessful )
    move "Listofstuff.dat" "DestinationFoldername" set %file% = "Listofstuff.dat" call :move if %errorlevel% == 1 ( echo Unsuccessful )
    
echo unsuccessfull: %errorlevel% >> unsuccessfull.log
```

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory, report directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "reportdir=u:"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65709918.txt"

:: delete report files

FOR %%a IN (moved failmove duplicate missing) DO DEL "%reportdir%\%%a.txt" >NUL 2>nul

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%a" (
  IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%a" (
   rem use following line to simply report that the destination file already exists
   REM >>"%reportdir%\duplicate.txt" ECHO %%a
   rem use following 2 lines to overwrite destination file
   ECHO y|MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%a" >NUL 2>nul
   IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"%reportdir%\failmove.txt" ECHO %%a) ELSE (>>"%reportdir%\moved.txt" ECHO %%a)
  ) ELSE (
   MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%a" >NUL
   >>"%reportdir%\moved.txt" ECHO %%a 
  )
 ) ELSE (>>"%reportdir%\missing.txt" ECHO %%a)
)

FOR %%a IN (moved failmove duplicate missing) DO IF EXIST "%reportdir%\%%a.txt" ECHO -----%%a-----&type "%reportdir%\%%a.txt"


GOTO :EOF
```

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the list filename.

I used a file named `q65709918.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing with this content:

```
ProjectFree.zip
Listofstuff.dat
notinsource.txt
has space IN name.txt
duplicate.txt
readonlyduplicate.txt
```

So, first delete the report files, then read the file `q65709918.txt` to get the names of the files to move. I included names that contain spaces, names that do not exist in the source and files that already exist in the destination, including a file that was read-only in the destination.

I don't know your policy about duplicates and read-only, so you could simply report the matter or overwrite - there's a report for each.

and finally, show each of the reports that have been generated...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i want a batch without extra files (no txt with a list of file). I though it was possible to just make a log from the simple "move" command or to make just one file for it. seems not.

Comment: It is possible, just more complicated.

Comment: ok, but i don't have the level to make it.

Comment: The issue is that in order to change your list, you have to change *something*. It's a lot better to change a text file than to change an executable, especially in a commercial environment. By changing just a text file, you can place the executable in a read-only secured directory.

Comment: My list never change, and it would be easier to use for my people if it's 1 unique file. It's not for commercial environnement, just private and association member.